# take two files from a directory in a single for loop using cshell

Tags: csh

I have two types of files in a single directory.

AB011.X
AB012.X 
AB013.X

and

AB011.Y
AB012.Y
AB013.Y

I want to pick up one from each group at a time if their basenames match 
I am using this code:

```
    for i in *.X
    do
      a=${i%.*}
      for j in *.Y
      do
        b=${j%.*}
        if ["$b" == "$a"] then
          echo "$a, $b"
        endif
      done
    done
```

This code is giving me the following error:

```
    line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
    line 10: `done'
```

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bash (ie. sh somecode.sh), working - based on the example code

3 changes - endif becomes fi, add ; after ], and add spaces just inside the braces...

```
 for i in *.X
   do
     a=${i%.*}
     for j in *.Y
       do
         b=${j%.*}
         if [ "$b" == "$a" ]; then
           echo "same $a, $b"
         fi
       done
     done
```

For cshell:

If using csh, then hopefully this snippet of csh script will get you on the right track: it prints out whether or not the Y version of the file exist for any given X version.

I'm using csh

```
#> csh --version

 tcsh 6.18.01 (Astron) 2012-02-14 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options 
 wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,color,filec
```

on Centos 7.

and I created the files thusly:

```
#> touch AB011.X AB011.Y AB012.X AB012.Y AB013.X AB013.Y
```

and ran the following script from a file called test.csh using csh:

```
#> csh test.csh
```

The contents of 'test.csh':

```
foreach v ( *.X )
    echo "$v"
    set a = "$v:r.Y"
    if ( -f $a ) then
        echo $a exist
    else
        echo $a does not exist
    endif
end
```

Output is:

```
AB011.X
AB011.Y exist
AB012.X
AB012.Y exist
AB013.X
AB013.Y exist
```

(I had answered this, but it was a bit too much bash-oriented. So I edited to be csh).

Comment: It returns:
`line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `('`
`line 14: `foreach v ( *.X )'`

Comment: I'll add more detail.

Comment: I was running it in bash, sorry. Now it works. Thanks.